# Matlab gets "crazy" after type special characters

Tags: keyboard, character-encoding, xmodmap, special-characters

I'm using a computer running Ubuntu and I'm connected through ssh to a RedHat machine where I use Matlab in command line mode (matlab -nodesktop). Matlab version is `7.10.0.499 (R2010a)`.

My problem occurs when I type any key which produces "special characters", such
as <kbd>ñ</kbd>, <kbd>á</kbd>, etc...

I managed to solve this, by setting this alias to matlab:

```
alias mat 'xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = Escape" -e "keycode 34 = Escape"; matlab -nodesktop; setxkbmap;'
```

...but this solution makes these changes globally, and I cannot type those characters (as long as matlab is running) in any other application including terminals, browsers, etc.

I read that this is a problem for this version of Matlab, but in that case,
a new question arises: if I use xmodmap in a terminal (xterm) connected to
other machine, why are those changes spread globally to my session?

Comment: As Caleb explains, a mapping change with xmodmap applies to the whole X session, and there's no easy alternate way. Maybe if you explain the Matlab issue we can come up with a better workaround.

Comment: When this problem happens I loose control of Matlab, because the prompt behaves as it should when the Enter key gets stuck. The only option is to suspend session (CTRL-z) and then kill the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your locale settings match on the local and remote machine: run `echo $LC_CTYPE` in a local terminal and in an ssh session. If they don't match, try again with Matlab with `LC_CTYPE` set to the correct value. If that doesn't work, try with `export LC_CTYPE=C` or with `export LC_CTYPE=en_US` (shot in the dark, I don't know the nature of the bug with Matlab).

If you're in a UTF-8 locale, try in an 8-bit locale such as latin1:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US luit ssh redhat-host
```

If fiddling with locales doesn't help, try something more radical: run `stty istrip` in the terminal before starting Matlab. This strips the 8th bit off the characters you type. When you enter an accented letter, Matlab will receive a garbage ASCII character, but nothing that should confuse it. Note that you should do this in addition to switching to a latin-1 locale such as `en_US`; in other locales, in particular in UTF-8, the garbage characters can be control characters.

There are a lot of stty settings, but I can't think of one that would just cause non-ASCII characters to be ignored. If you experiment with `stty`, you can revert to sane defaults with `stty sane`. The changes are local to a terminal.

Comment: Your radical solution worked.  
With stty istrip, matlab receives those characters, and for "ñ" it prints C1...  
I don't need the special characters inside Matlab, but by accident they sometimes get pressed.  
So, this is a very good solution, and one that I didn't find anywhere else.
Thanks!

Comment: @nozimica: Note that in a UTF-8 locale (which you seem to be in since `ñ` is two bytes), some accented letters will end up sending a control character to Matlab (e.g. ś → `E^[`). That could be a problem, so I recommend doing both: switch to a latin1 locale and `stty istrip`.

Comment: I've just tested, and `ś` and other special characters do no harm to the matlab session. In particular, `ś` prints just `E`. About the `stty sane` command, it doesn't restore the original settings, but `stty -istrip` does. Very good is the option to negate a command in `stty` just by prepending a `-`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The changes you are making are not local to Matlab. The command you setup an alias for edits the keymap of the current X session, then starts Matlab. The changes end up on your machine because you have x-forwarding properties in your ssh session that allow programs to talk to the upstream X server. You could just as easily run an xterm on the remote computer and it would launch locally, because that shell knows that it's upstream X session is through your SSH connection.

In fact if this were not the case, your keyboard map fix would do nothing at all. Your local X server is the right place to set that, and, as far as I know, the only place that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this bug was fixed for MATLAB R2010b(7.11). The bug report can be found behind an inconvenient (but free) MathWorks account login here:

> [Extended characters typed or pasted into a nodesktop instance of MATLAB running in a xterm causes infinite loop of prompts to be displayed](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/624817) (bug 624817).

Comment: (But to my disappointment, our university is still stuck on R2010a…)

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with special characters on matlab, running it like this solved it for me:

```
LANG=us_US.UTF-8 QT_IM_MODULE=xim GTK_IM_MODULE=xim XMODIFIERS=XIM matlab
```